# Divisão entre valores - Query SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Galera, na consulta abaixo, está trazendo da seguinte forma.

```
Ano  Mes  Horas  total_horas
2018  1    107    766 H
2018  1    225    766 H
```

Sendo assim, quero que traga em outra coluna a divisão da coluna "Horas" pela coluna "total_horas", trazendo dessa forma.

```
Ano  Mes  Horas  total_horas    media
2018  1    107    766 H        0,139996
2018  1    225    766 H        0,293735
```

Segue a consulta abaixo.

```
select
t1.Ano,t1.Mês,t1.horas,t2.total_horas
from
(select sum(f.C06) horas, DATEPART(month, TarFechamento) Mês, DATEPART(YEAR,     TarFechamento) Ano, FC.Valor Tipo 
 from  Tarefa t 
    INNER JOIN Usuario u on t.UsuIDResponsavel = u.UsuID and u.UsuIDGrupo = 7 
    INNER JOIN FRM_10 F ON F.TarefaID = T.TarID AND F.C04 IS NOT NULL
    INNER JOIN FormularioCampoValor FC ON FC.ValorID = F.C04
    where t.ProID in (9,3,12,7,10,4,5,2) AND T.TarTipID NOT IN (1048,1049,1050) and datepart(year,tarfechamento)>= 2018 and t.TarStatus = 9
 group by DATEPART(YEAR, TarFechamento),  datepart(month,TarFechamento),     FC.Valor)t1

left join

(select concat(cast(sum(f.C06) as varchar(100)),' ','H')  total_horas,     DATEPART(month, TarFechamento) Mês, DATEPART(YEAR, TarFechamento) Ano
 from  Tarefa t 
    INNER JOIN Usuario u on t.UsuIDResponsavel = u.UsuID and u.UsuIDGrupo = 7 
    INNER JOIN FRM_10 F ON F.TarefaID = T.TarID AND F.C04 IS NOT NULL
    INNER JOIN FormularioCampoValor FC ON FC.ValorID = F.C04
    where t.ProID in (9,3,12,7,10,4,5,2) AND T.TarTipID NOT IN (1048,1049,1050) and datepart(year,tarfechamento)>= 2018 and t.TarStatus = 9
    group by DATEPART(YEAR, TarFechamento),  datepart(month,TarFechamento))t2 on t1.Ano = t2.Ano and t1.Mês = t2.Mês
```

OBS: Tentei realizar na consulta externa acima dessa forma porém, sem sucesso..

```
select
t1.Ano,t1.Mês,t1.horas / t2.total_horas
```

Comment: t1.horas  e  t2.total_horas são inteiros, time ou outro tipo?

Comment: @AriSantos, são inteiros

Comment: tentei em um banco que tenho para testes e o codigo 
 select
 t1.Ano,t1.Mês,t1.horas / t2.total_horas
deveria ter funcionado
qual a saida quando vc utiliza ele?

Comment: select t1.Ano,t1.Mês,t1.horas,t2.total_horas,CAST(t1.horas AS FLOAT)/CAST(t2.total_horas AS FLOAT) AS MEDIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando vc utiliza

```
select t1.Ano,t1.Mês,t1.horas / t2.total_horas
```

por ti.horas e t2.total_horas ser inteiros vamos ter como resposta valores inteiros ou seja

```
Ano  Mes  Horas  total_horas    media
2018  1    107    766 H        0
2018  1    225    766 H        0
```

entao faça a divisão da seguinte forma para ter resultados em float

```
SELECT t1.Ano,t1.Mês,CAST(t1.horas AS float) / CAST(t2.total_horas AS float)
```

Como total_horas tem que ser int para poder executar a divisão
substitua

```
concat(cast(sum(f.C06) as varchar(100)),' ','H')  total_horas
```

por

sum(f.C06) as total_horas

e se vc quer o concat o add no select:

```
SELECT t1.Ano,t1.Mês,concat(cast(t2.total_horas as varchar(100)),' ','H')  total_horas,CAST(t1.horas AS float) / CAST(t2.total_horas AS float)
```

Comment: deu erro. Ocorreu a mensagem:

"Erro ao converter tipo de dados varchar em float.
Aviso: o valor nulo é eliminado por uma agregação ou outra operação SET"

Comment: Qual campo deu erro? parece que um deles é varchar e não inteiro

Comment: Realmente seu t2.total_horas é varchar e não inteiro:
concat(cast(sum(f.C06) as varchar(100)),' ','H')

Comment: Minha sugestão é tirar o concat da subquery e executar ele na query principal apenas na hora de retorna os resultados

Comment: Deu certo @Ari Santos, retirei o concat e funcionou. Obrigado.